# Using jquery datepicker in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use jQuery's datepicker without much success. Here is the related code:
The problem is that I am not getting jQuery's datepicker to show. The page renders an input tag with type text. It has the correct value displayed. However, when I click in it, the Date Time picker is not displayed.
Model:

```
    public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string MediaPath { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

}
```

View snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker();         
    });
</script>
```

....

```
@Html.TextBox("PublicationDate", Model.PublicationDate.ToString("yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly isn't working? I see you're formating your date so it shows only the year part, is that the issue?

Comment: This works fine for me. Do you have any errors showing on the browser's console? Is it possible you're viewing an old cached page?

Comment: Maybe a CSS issue? Use a tool like firebug and see if the datepicker code is inserted. I though it will be inserted just before the `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.asp.net/post/5289561.aspx

i m also having same issue..but i tried this and it work well for me..

1. Open BundleConfig.cs and modify the style bundle "~/Content/themes/base/css" as follows:

   ```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.all.css"));
   ```
2. Open your _layout.cs and add the following just before the closing tag of the

   ```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   ```
3. Finally to test your view, open your index.cshtml and add this at the end

   ```
   <p>Date:
   <input type="text" id="txtDate" class="datefield" />
   </p>

       @section Scripts{
       @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                   $(".datefield").datepicker();
         });
        </script>
           }
   ```